# Excel VBA insert cell before current cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the right way to insert a cell before the current cell.

I'm looping through a number of cells in a row - when it finds the right value I want it shifted to the right.

I've tried this code: (located post code has a value pointing to the offset relative to the starting active cell)

```
Dim shiftrng as Range

For ctr = locatedPostCodeIndex To 4

    Set shiftrng = Range(cll.Offset(0, locatedPostCodeIndex)).Select
    shiftrng.Insert.xlShiftToRight

Next
```

I get an error: `Method range of object _global failed`

What is the correct way to insert a cell before a cell?

Comment: `shiftRange` and `shiftrng` are correct?

Comment: Hi yes, sorry the typo cam in editing the post. Updated now.

Comment: what do you do with the `ctr` variable?

Comment: Refer to @Jeeped's answer, but also there should be no `.` between `Insert` and `xlShiftToRight`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not add `.Select` when setting a variable to a range object and you do not require wrapping the cell offset destination in `Range(...)`.

```
Set shiftrng = cll.Offset(0, locatedPostCodeIndex)
```

Comment: In fact if you're not doing anything else with `shiftrng` you can insert it at the range directly, i.e. `cll.Offset(0, locatedPostCodeIndex).Insert xlShiftToRight`

Comment: Thank you - I used your example above but still came up with an object error. I realised in your example there is no period between insert and xlshofttoright - removed that and it worked